# Thermodo iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not quite sure how to install the Thermodo iOS SDK manually and haven't found much in the way of help online.

Has anyone had success in following their small set of instructions?

Here's a link to their developer page: https://github.com/thermodo/ThermodoSDK-iOS/

I followed the "Manual Instructions" but Xcode continues to error out.

The first error is: "Cannot find interface declaration for 'THMThermodo'" This sounds to me like an issue with a missing `#import` line. If I add the `#import` to the .h file that throws the error, I get a new error:

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../Documents/Development/MyThermodo/ThermodoSDK/libThermodoSDK.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/.../Documents/Development/MyThermodo/ThermodoSDK/libThermodoSDK.a (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_THMThermodo", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_THMThermodo_$_Conversion in THMThermodo+Conversion.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common error, and you'll run into it with many third party libraries. The relevant part of the output you're seeing is:

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

If you search for that phrase you'll find lots of similar questions with lots of good suggestions. In a nutshell, the error usually means that you've left some files out of the project, or forgotten to check the target membership box in the file inspector to include them in the target you're building.